# Using cURL Handle as Array Key

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

I'm using curl_multi functions to request multiple URLs and process them as they complete. As one connection completes all I really have is the cURL handle (and associated data) from `curl_multi_info_read()`.

The URLs come from a job queue, and once processed I need to remove the job from the queue. I don't want to rely on the URL to identify the job (there *shouldn't* be duplicate URLs, but what if there *is*).

The solution I've worked up so far is to use the cURL handle as an array key pointing to the jobid. Form what I can tell, when treated as a string the handle is something like:

```
"Resource id #1"
```

That seams reasonably unique to me. The basic code is:

```
$ch = curl_init($job->getUrl());
$handles[$ch] = $job;
//then later
$done = curl_multi_info_read($master);
$handles[$done['handle']]->delete();
curl_multi_remove_handle($master, $done['handle']);
```

**Is the cURL handle safe to use in this way?**

Or is there a better way to map the cURL handles to the job that created them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will probably work thanks to some implicit type cast, but it doesn't feel right to me at all.  I think it's begging for trouble somewhere down the line, with future versions that treat resources differently, different platforms...

I personally wouldn't do it, but use numeric indexes.

Comment: But with numeric indexes I'd still have to somehow map the original job to the cURL handle. You think array_search($ch, $jobs) would work?

Comment: @Tim I don't know, you'd have to try... True, you'd have to map the original job somehow with a numeric index, but IMO it's worth the effort. `array[$ch]` smells really evil!

Answer (score 9):

Store private data inside the cURL easy handle, e.g. some job ID:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, $job->getId());
// then later
$id = curl_getinfo($done['handle'], CURLINFO_PRIVATE);
```

This "private data" feature is not (yet) documented in the PHP manual. It was introduced already in PHP 5.2.4. It allows you to store and retrieve a string of your choice inside the cURL handle. Use it for a key that uniquely identifies the job.

Edit: Feature is now [documented](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) in the PHP manual (search for `CURLOPT_PRIVATE` within the page).

Comment: I don't know why it is'nt the accepted answer. It's a working solution (I've tested it), and the other answers only tell what's wrong...

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree with Pekka... it will probably work but it smells bad. id use straight up integers as Pekka suggests or wrap the handles in a simple class and then use `spl_object_hash` or have the constructor generate a `uniqid` when its set up.

Comment: Not sure wrapping the handles in a class helps, because all I get back from curl_multi_info_read() is the [unwrapped] handle.

Comment: Yeah i guess youd have to make a wrapper for the curl_multi functionality as well.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. I'm at this same problem, so creating a wrapper will still leave us with the problem that the only thing we have is the handle. The idea is we want O(1) lookup using a hash map of some sort. But, what's the best way to get a key value based on the resource. And of course... `Yo dawg, I got a wrapper for your wrapper so you can wrap while you're wrapping.`